# Removing & Updating Table Rows Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, attr

I am a novice when it comes to jQuery so please bear with me a little and I apologies for my poor coding in advance.

The logic to my code is simple or at least that was the aim.

A jQuery script checks a type field and then gets its values and builds a table. That all works 100%.

The issue comes when deleting rows and then updating the table id's on the new appended rows that is generated by clicking on the new row button.

The new rows do not delete.

Here is the code but I have also created a jsfiddle so you can check it out live, but there are some bugs that are not there on the site - for instance you need to double click the button for some reason for it to work

JS:

```
$('.purchase-order-button').on('click', function(){

    var buildcotable = '';
    var buildtrs = $('#formentry15').val();
    var coArray = '';
    var coArrayNumber = 1;

    buildcotable += '<div class="table-responsive">';
    buildcotable += '<table class="table table-bordered">';

    buildcotable += '<thead>';
    buildcotable += '<th class="text-center">CO Number</th>';
    buildcotable += '<th class="text-center">CO Price</th>';
    buildcotable += '<th class="text-center">Options</th>';
    buildcotable += '</thead>';

    buildcotable += '<tbody id="jquerypotable">';

    //lets do a check and see how many are listed
    if(buildtrs.indexOf(',') !== -1){

        coArray = buildtrs.split(',');

        $.each(coArray, function(){

            var splitCoArray = this.split('=');
            var coArrayPrice = splitCoArray[1].trim().replace('£', '');
            var coArrayCode = splitCoArray[0].trim();

            buildcotable += '<tr id="jqueryporow'+coArrayNumber+'">';
            buildcotable += '<td><input type="text" value="'+coArrayCode+'" id="jqueryponumber'+coArrayNumber+'" class="form-control"></td>';
            buildcotable += '<td><input type="text" value="'+coArrayPrice+'" id="jquerypovalue'+coArrayNumber+'" class="form-control"></td>';
            buildcotable += '<td class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-danger delete-co-row" id="deletepo'+coArrayNumber+'">Delete CO Number</a></td>';
            buildcotable += '</tr>';

            coArrayNumber += 1;

        });

    } else {

        if(buildtrs == '' || buildtrs == 'TBC'){

            buildcotable += '<tr id="jqueryporow1">';
            buildcotable += '<td><input type="text" value="" id="jqueryponumber1" class="form-control"></td>';
            buildcotable += '<td><input type="text" value="" id="jquerypovalue1" class="form-control"></td>';
            buildcotable += '<td class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-danger delete-co-row" id="deletepo1">Delete CO Number</a></td>';
            buildcotable += '</tr>';

        } else {

            var splitSingleCoArray = buildtrs.split('=');
            var coSinglePrice = splitSingleCoArray[1].trim().replace('£', '');
            var coSingleCode = splitSingleCoArray[0].trim();

            buildcotable += '<tr id="jqueryporow1">';
            buildcotable += '<td><input type="text" value="'+coSingleCode+'" id="jqueryponumber1" class="form-control"></td>';
            buildcotable += '<td><input type="text" value="'+coSinglePrice+'" id="jquerypovalue1" class="form-control"></td>';
            buildcotable += '<td class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-danger delete-co-row" id="deletepo1">Delete CO Number</a></td>';
            buildcotable += '</tr>';

        }

    }

    buildcotable += '</tbody>';

    buildcotable += '</table>';
    buildcotable += '<p><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-block" id="addnewpo">Add New CO Number</a></p>';
    buildcotable += '<p><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" id="ubldonepo">Done</a></p>';
    buildcotable += '</div>';

    $('.ubl-section-7').html(buildcotable);

    $('.ubl-section-7').show();
    $('.model-background').fadeIn(500);

    //add new row
    $('#addnewpo').on('click', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        var numPoRows = $("#jquerypotable > tr").length;
        var makeNewRowNum = numPoRows + 1;

        var createnewporow = '<tr id="jqueryporow'+makeNewRowNum+'">';

        createnewporow += '<td><input type="text" value="" id="jqueryponumber'+makeNewRowNum+'" class="form-control"></td>';
        createnewporow += '<td><input type="text" value="" id="jquerypovalue'+makeNewRowNum+'" class="form-control"></td>';
        createnewporow += '<td class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-danger delete-co-row-new" id="deletepo'+makeNewRowNum+'">Delete CO Number</a></td>';

        createnewporow += '</tr>';

        $('#jquerypotable').append(createnewporow);

    });

    //delete row
    $('#jquerypotable > tr').on('click', '.delete-co-row', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        var getCoId = $(this).attr('id');
        var coLastChar = parseInt(getCoId.substr(getCoId.length - 1));
        var coHowManyRows = parseInt($("#jquerypotable > tr").length);
        var makeMinusId = '';
        var newi = coLastChar;

        if(coLastChar == coHowManyRows){

            $('#jqueryporow'+coLastChar).remove();

        } else {

            //before removing rows we need to rebuild the information given.
            for(newi; newi <= coHowManyRows; newi++){

                if(newi == coLastChar){

                    $('#jqueryporow'+newi).remove();

                } else {

                    makeMinusId = (newi - 1);

                    $('#jqueryporow'+newi).attr('id', 'jqueryporow'+makeMinusId);
                    $('#jqueryponumber'+newi).attr('id', 'jqueryponumber'+makeMinusId);
                    $('#jquerypovalue'+newi).attr('id', 'jquerypovalue'+makeMinusId);
                    $('#deletepo'+newi).attr('id', 'deletepo'+makeMinusId);

                }

            }

        }

    });

});
```

[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/robertg/zmozus1b/9/)

Any help is gratefully received

Comment: Far too much code to wade through, please read this [mcve].  First glance would suggest using `$(this)` and adding linking `data-` attributes rather than parsing the button's `id`

Answer (score 0):

You added an `eventListener` to the delete buttons at the initialization of the page but didnt do it again when creating the rows. I suggest adding the following code to your `addnewpo` button:

```
$('#addnewpo').on('click', function(e){
  // your original code here
  //...

  //now add an event listener to the new deletebuttons
  $('#jquerypotable > tr').on('click', '.delete-co-row-new', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  });
});
```

Comment: furthermore add  the `#` to ur `href` in `<a href="" class="purchase-order-button btn btn-danger">Click Here</a> ` to prevent the double click behavior

Answer (score 0):

I Found the issue, the issue was the listener needed to remove the tr.

so instead of:

```
/now add an event listener to the new deletebuttons
$('#jquerypotable > tr').on('click', '.delete-co-row', function(e){
```

It needed to be:

```
/now add an event listener to the new deletebuttons
$('#jquerypotable').on('click', '.delete-co-row', function(e){
```

Thanks everyone for trying to help :)